# IPFS module not found while running React app

Tags: reactjs, ipfs

[image]

I am using a react app inside another react app. The one within is having IPFS usage. I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found he solution. Install all dependencies at one place at outer react app and not individually.